# AngularJS - Connect to another controller in the App.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app.js file I am trying to call to another js file with my controller, but I cannot handle this now.

I'm trying to use controllerURl, but he insists on calling the standard file controllers.js`

May some help how I can call to another file?

**App.js**

```
.state('app.mapa', {
  url: '/mapa',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/mapa.html',
      controllerUrl: 'controllers/mapa.controller'
    }
  }
})
```

**mapa.controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myModule", []) 
.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) 
  { 
    console.log("teste");
    $http.get("http://localhost:20432/WebService1.asmx/listPessoas") 
    .then(function (response) { $scope.pessoas = response.data; }); });
```

**Mapa.html Template**

```
<html ng-app="myModule">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="myController" data-ng-init="init()">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark" >
      <h1 class="title">Map</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div class="map-container" ng-show="$root.enableMap">
        <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think if you call from the service is more appropriate.

Comment: Agree this code should be going in a factory or the service.

Comment: read this, it's helpful. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

Comment: thank you, but you know why when I call my controllerURl he not called mapa.controller.js?

Comment: did you inject the dependency in your main app.js? have you included your controller file in the index?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to have?

If you want to carry a value from a controller to another one you can  use `$rootScope` . Every App has one `Root Scope` only and you can inject it  in your `ng-controller`.

But the better practice would be using a `service`